# Increase sampling frequency for every 1 second in dataframe by repeating the last row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with variable sampling frequency <30 hz. I want to increase the sampling frequency to 30 by repeating the last row of dataframe for every second.
The timestamp column in my dataframe does not have milliseconds. The same time stamp is repeated for all the rows for that second. Also data is not continuous some of the seconds are missing in between.
My dataframe `df` has columns `['Timestamp','vm','angle']`.

Here is what i tried

```
def samfreq(args):
    size = len(args)
    inc= 30-size
    args=args.append( args.iloc[[-1]*inc] )
    args = args.reset_index(drop=True)
    return args


df= df.resample('1S',on='Timestamp').apply(samfreq)
```

Running the above code gives me this error

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

If the data is continuous i dont think i will get the above error. How do i increase the sampling frequency for all the seconds in the data ignoring the missing seconds inbetween.

Here is a sample code to generate data similar to the one i am woking on.I purposefully missed a second in the data to mimic my data.

```
d = {'Timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2016-04-15 10:36:47', end='2016-04-15 10:36:47', periods=12), 'vm': np.random.randn(12),'angle':np.random.randn(12)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d = {'Timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2016-04-15 10:36:49', end='2016-04-15 10:36:49', periods=15), 'vm': np.random.randn(15),'angle':np.random.randn(15)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
```

How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use *groupby* instead of *resample* and it will work as you expect:

```
df.groupby('Timestamp').apply(samfreq).reset_index(drop = True)
```